# How can I safely install Jupyter / IPython 4 over a conda installation?

Tags: ipython, conda, jupyter

IPython 4 is out! And I'm keen to try it. But I am running iPython under conda.

Before conda adds version 4 to its repository, is there a safe way to install IPython 4 manually?

I tried:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter
```

and it corrupted my installation. Any ideas?

Comment: It should be safe to `conda uninstall ipython` and then `pip install jupyter` into your environment.

Answer (score 8):

For me, similar to what Thomas mentioned in his comments, the following worked

```
conda update conda
conda uninstall ipython
conda install jupyter
```

The first two steps may not be necessary, but better save than sorry.

Comment: It seems that my version (???) does not have `uninstall` option, so what I did was to use `conda remove ipython` instead. There is ??? there because during the process the whole `conda` broke down and now I cannot even use  `conda`. I am now getting the following error: `ImportError: No module named requests`